# Oracle to Excel File C#

Tags: c#, excel, oracle

I am trying to get an easy way to write oracle tables to Excel. I cant find an way without iterating over each single row. Can I use the data table as an "object"? I would like to reference the datatable and insert it into the mypath in a folder directory. Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
 namespace ConsoleApplication4
        {
       class Program
           {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Submit the Shared Folder
            String myDir = @"S:\x\xx\xxx\2016-12-30, Collab                                 
            //Name Deposit File 
            String myFile = "COLLAB_CARE_INTEROP" + ".xlsx";
            //Combine the name
            String myPath = myDir + myFile;
            //If file is found (myPath) then delete before replacing
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(myPath);
            if (fileInfo.Exists) fileInfo.Delete();

            //Declare helper variables.
            string workBookName = myPath;
            string pivotTableName = @"Recip";
            string workSheetName = @"Data";


        //Oracle Connection For Excel Source 
        string oradb = "Data Source=xx.xx;User Id=xxx;Password=xxxxxxx;";
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
        conn.Open();
        // GET COLLAB CARE DATA  //
        string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * from COLLAB_CARE_CLAIMS;
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // C# dr name of file 
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);


    }
}
```

}

Comment: This question is tagged under c# to export a table from Oracle to Excel. Is your goal to perform this task using C# only or are you looking for general solution to get your Oracle table data in excel format ? If that is the case then see this link about how to export your table to excel using SQL Developer a free tool made available by Oracle - [https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/impexp.htm#BABBHIJF](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/impexp.htm#BABBHIJF)

Comment: @lazyPanda The issue for research has been every example is being done using Oracle.DataAccess.Client; Of which makes row by row iteration. I need C# code that allows me the ability to drop an oracle table into a newly created excel, then I can use inter-op to create pivots. Thanks